# Select radio buttons with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

How would i go about selection radio buttons with scrapy?

I am trying to select the following

```
formdata={'rd1':'E'} does not work

<input type="radio" name="rd1" value="E" checked="checked" />Employee
<input type="radio" name="rd2" value="o" />Other
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [lxml.cssselector](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) to select the radio buttons.

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
>>> str = """
... '<input type="radio" name="rd1" value="E" checked="checked" />Employee
... <input type="radio" name="rd2" value="o" />Other'
... """
>>> input_sel = CSSSelector('input[name="rd1"]')
>>> lx = lxml.html.fromstring(str)
>>> input_sel(lx)
[<InputElement b7e7665c name='rd1' type='radio'>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just bumped into a similar problem (that's why I'm here of course). This wonderful site of the City of Chicago (https://webapps1.chicago.gov/buildingrecords/home) requires your bot to 'Aggree' to their 'liability disclaimer' (this is very funny indeed!) with a radio-button and a click on a button. I solved the problem with the help of `scrapy.FormRequest.from_response`:

```
def agreement_failed(response):
    # check the result of your first post here
    return  # something if it's a failure or nothing if it's not


class InspectionsListSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'inspections_list'
    start_urls = ['https://webapps1.chicago.gov/buildingrecords/home']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid='agreement',
            formdata = {"agreement": "Y",
                        "submit": "submit"},
            callback = self.after_agreement
            )

    def after_agreement(self, response):
        if agreement_failed(response):
            self.logger.error("agreement failed!")
            return
        else:
            ... # whatever you are going to do after
```

Together with the code of the page it's pretty self-explanatory. You may also need other parameters of your form described here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=FormRequest()#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response

P.S. The next pages' riddle is solvable too in the same way. :)