# scrapy how to select and pass radio button in formdata

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and using `scrapy with python 2.7` for submitting a form which contains different form elemens like dropdowns, checkboxes and `radio buttons.` I have done with dropdowns, checkboxes but I don't have any idea about passing radio buttons selected using `FormRequest.from_response`.

I have tried the same way like checkbox with syntax as `name : value` but it is not working. And also can't find any material regarding radio buttons on internet. Below is my code.

```
return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                     formxpath='//*[@id="main_form"]',
                                     formdata={'anwall': 'javascript and R',
                                               'mne': '3',
                                               'mxe': '5',
                                               'chbox1' : '4',
                                               'chbox2' : '4',
                                               'rd1' : '200000', #name : value
                                               'rd2' : '20000',
                                               'rd3' : '300000',
                                               'rd4' : '30000'},
                                     callback=self.next_page)

def next_page(self, response):
    open_in_browser(response)
```

And html code is :

```
<input name="chbox1" value="4" style="display:none;" class="selCl_checkbox" type="checkbox">

<input name="rd1" id="minSalLac5" class="from_minLac" value="200000" onclick="getSalaryVal();" type="radio">
```

How can I select radio button and pass it using formadata. Any idea is really helpfull.

Edit:

Also I can select radio button like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113430/10011103). But how to pass it in formdata.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty certain it is name:value, however there seems to be some javascript attached to this radio button, so maybe the frontend does something more to modify the formdata?
Could you post the website you are crawling so we can try to replicate this?

Comment: @Granitosaurus Thanks for your reply but Sorry! I'm crawling a website after **authenticated login**. So you might not get permission to this website. there is `onclick` attribute for `getSalaryVal()` function but not sure that it is having any effect. Should I post this function here? I'm slecting value as salary  from this radio button. By the way here is link of this page : [http://recruiter.monsterindia.com/v2/resumedatabase/resume_search.html]. And what else we can try.

Comment: You can try opening up web browser inspector and see exactly the form your browser is sending when you click the button.

Comment: @Granitosaurus I have already tried that but the problem is same i.e, form is not showing radio button values selected.